# Types union and TS2554 issue

Tags: typescript

I'm facing the following TS issue which I can't solve. I've got `Comparator` object which is a set of functions.

```
type GenericCompareFn = (condValue: any, browserValue: any) => boolean

type IsSetCompareFn = (browserValue: any) => boolean

export type ComparatorType = {
  equals: GenericCompareFn
  not_equals: GenericCompareFn
  contains: GenericCompareFn
  not_contains: GenericCompareFn
  lower: GenericCompareFn
  greater: GenericCompareFn
  between: GenericCompareFn
  in: GenericCompareFn
  not_in: GenericCompareFn
  is_set: IsSetCompareFn
  is_not_set: IsSetCompareFn
}

export type Operation = keyof ComparatorType
```

And now I got `evaluate` function which should call specified `Comparator`'s method based on `Operation`, but typechecking fails even if I have it inside `switch/case` construct:

```
const evalFn = Comparator[operation]
if (!evalFn)
  // I'm processing external input so I cannot rely on operation variable at all, hence Exception
  throw new ConditionEvaluationError(
    `Given operation ${operation} doesn't exist`
  )

switch (operation) {
  case "is_set":
  case "is_not_set":
    // here I get "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1. ts(2554)"
    return evalFn(attribute.getBrowserValue())
  default:
    return evalFn(value, attribute.getBrowserValue())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of
`const evalFn = Comparator[operation]` is `const evalFn: GenericCompareFn | IsSetCompareFn`.

The switch can narrow down the variable under switch but does not narrow down unrelated variables (namely evalFn).

However, if you take `Comparator[operation]` with `operation` narrowed down, the resulting function is narrowed down as well.

Thus, the following code type-check without problems:

```
switch (operation) {
  case "is_set":
  case "is_not_set":
    const evalFn1Arg = Comparator[operation];
    return evalFn1Arg(attribute.getBrowserValue())
  default:
    const evalFn2Arg = Comparator[operation];
    return evalFn2Arg(value, attribute.getBrowserValue())
}
```